# Can we overload `==` operator in C++ to compare two strings?

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading

If we want to compare two strings without using `strcmp()` function, then can we overload `==` operator to compare two strings ?

Comment: `operator==` is already overloaded for `std::string` ;). Thus, you could do something like `std::string(str1) == std::string(str2)`.

Comment: You can add further overloads to your own namespaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you meant to overload `operator==` with c-style string, then the answer is **No**. The [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) is supposed to be used for customizing operators for operands of **user-defined types**.

From the standard, $13.5/6 Overloaded operators [over.oper] (emphasis mine)

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or
>   be a non-member function that has **at least one parameter whose type is
>   a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
>   enumeration**.

Note if you meant [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), the answer is still **No**. STL has provided the implementation of [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) for `std::string` and you can't modify it. In fact, you don't need to overload it at all, just using it will be fine.

**EDIT**

If you want to overload it for your own class, it's fine. Such as

```
Class X {
    //...
};
bool operator==(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) { 
    // do the comparison and return the result
}
```

then

```
X x1, x2;
//...
if (x1 == x2) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I mean to say that if i make a class having a char array as it's data member and i make two objects of this class.Then can i compare these objects by overloading `==` ??

Comment: @a874 Yes, you can, but you don't need, because there is `std::string`.

Comment: @user2807083 Better yet, there is (or soon will be) string_view.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it already overloaded?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
int main()
{
    std::string a = "Ala";
    std::string b = "Ala";
    if(a==b)
        std::cout<<"same\n";
    else
        std::cout<<"but different\n";
}
```

The code above worked for me (CodeBlocks)

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution that will give you less worries. I've just written the function `equal(a,b)` that tells you whether or not two strings are the same (feel free to copy all the code and test it in your terminal):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//PRE: Two strings.
//POST: True if they are equal. False if they are different. 
bool equal(const string& a, const string&b) {
    int len_a = a.length();
    int len_b = b.length();

    if (len_a != len_b) return false;

    //do this if they are equal
    for (int i = 0; i < len_a; ++i) {
        if (a[i] != b[i])   return false;
    }
    return true;
}



int main() {
    string a, b;
    cout << "Write two strings, with a space in between:" << endl;

    cin >> a >> b;
    if (equal(a,b))  cout << "they are equal" << endl;
    else            cout << "they are different" << endl;

}
```